# How to create only a certain number of rows

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a piece of code where the user is able to add a new row into a table:

Below is the code:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {

    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");
    var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");

    $('.gridTxt').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxt' readonly='readonly' /><span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val())
        $options.append($optionsText);
    });

    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($options);
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

    form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;

    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
    form.questionText.value = "";


}
```

What I want to do though is to only create a certain maximum number of rows. The maximum amount of rows that can be added has to match the number which has been posted from another page:

```
{$_POST['textQuestion']}
```

So for example if the number of the `$_POST['textQuestion']` is 20, then no more than 20 rows can be created.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this JS is embedded in a PHP File, you can add a line to your JS function like

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
    if (qnum>=<?php echo (int)$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>) return();

    // the rest of your code
    ++qnum;
}
```

This will render as:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
    if (qnum>=20) return();

    // the rest of your code
    ++qnum;
}
```

---

**OR**

---

If the JS is not embedded in your PHP, you will need to set the appropriate JS variable from within PHP ..perhaps like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxRows=<?php echo (int)$_POST['textQuestion']; ?>;
</script>
```

then in your JS file...

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
    if (qnum>=maxRows) return();

    // the rest of your code
    ++qnum;
}
```